# CSS 3.0 animation on iOS

Tags: ios, css, animation

How do I get this code to work on iOS?

My iPad won't show the translate property.
I have read about using `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` and `-webkit-transform: translate3d`, but its not working.

```
.logo-box {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:115px;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    -webkit-transition: .7s;
    -moz-transition: .7s;
    -o-transition: .7s;
    -ms-transition: .7s;
    transition: .7s;
}

.logo-box:hover {
    transform: translate(0,-20px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-20px); /** Safari & Chrome **/
    -o-transform: translate(0,-20px); /** Opera **/
    -moz-transform: translate(0,-20px); /** Firefox **/
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    -o-transition: .5s;
    -ms-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;
}
```

Comment: how can you hover in a tablet?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, adding perspective helped me out. You may want to try adding it and see it if works. You can read about it here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_perspective.asp